# Is it possible to change the border color of the strip wrapper from the jQuery plugin GalleryView?

Tags: jquery

I found a very nice jquery plugin: http://spaceforaname.com/gallery-light.html

I want to change the border color of the strip wrapper (default is white)

```
position: absolute; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; top: 304px; left: 74px; height: 98px; width: 98px; border: 2px solid white;
```

The problem is that the border color seems to be generated via javascript

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link doesn't work, but you could try using more specific CSS or even using `!important`, like this:

```
.wrapperwhatever{
border-color: white !important;
}
```

OR

```
body bodycontainer .wrapperwhatever{
border-color:white !important;
}
```